# When did "our" stop being used as an adjective (as in "other our dominions", "any our Subjects")?

Tags: adjectives, possessives, syntactic-analysis, historical-change

While reading a [letter written by Queen Elizabeth I of England in 1588](http://www.luminarium.org/renlit/elizinvasion.htm), I came across a certain construction that doesn't seem to be grammatical in English:

> RIGHT trustie, and righte welbelovid cousines wee greete you well. Whereas heertofore upon the advertismentes, from time to time and from sondrie places, of the great preparations of foren forces, made with a full intention to invade this our Realme and **other our dominions**

If I were writing a letter like this, I would have to use some wording like "other dominions of ours" or "our other dominions". (Or maybe something like "other(s) of our dominions", but I'm not quite sure about that—it may be material for another question.)

I checked the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) entries for *our* and *other,* but I didn't see any examples or explanation of the grammar of "other our". I would appreciate it if anyone could point me to a source that explains the grammar of this construction, and why it doesn't seem to be grammatical in the English of today.

I do have a guess about what is going on. To me, it seems like Elizabeth is using *our* as a "regular" adjective, and not as a determiner. That is, I think the structure of "other our dominions" is the same as the structure of a phrase like "other British dominions".

### *Our* in modern English doesn't act like an (ordinary) adjective

This usage doesn't seem to be possible in standard modern English: I think *our* for me always functions as a determiner. This is consistent with the analysis where *our* in modern English is viewed as a "genitive/possessive pronoun" (not as an adjective). Pronouns are used in place of noun phrases, and we can say that a word like *her* stands for a genitive/possessive noun phrase like "the Queen's". According to this analysis, it makes sense that I can't say things like "other her dominions", because I also can't say things like "other the Queen's dominions". Genitive noun phrases and genitive pronouns can't be put into the "attributive adjective slot" in a modern English noun phrase.

### *Our* in Elizabeth's letter seems to be used like an ordinary adjective

But the description of *our* as a "possessive adjective" seems to be more valid in older forms of English. For example, the OED says that *our* originally inflected like an adjective: "Old English *ūre,* adjective, was declined like ordinary adjectives in *-e,* e.g. masculine accusative singular *ūrne*, masculine and neuter genitive singular *ūres*, masculine and neuter dative singular and common plural *ūrum*, etc. "

If I'm right about *our* being used as an adjective and not as a determiner in the quoted passage, I'd like to know at what point this use of *our* (and other "possessive adjectives") became impossible in standard English.

### Other examples that I found

I searched Google for some more examples of the phrase "other our dominions", and found that it occurred as late as 1665, in the [Charter of Carolina](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/17th_century/nc01.asp). It seems quite possible though that a charter might use archaic language, so this doesn't show that the construction was in common use in the 17th century.

I also found an early example (actually several examples) of this construction in Edward I's Confirmation of the Charters in 1297. Interestingly, it looks like a parallel structure is used in the French version: English "other our ministers" corresponds to French "[autres nos ministres](https://books.google.com/books?id=qA4zAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA484&dq=%22autres+nos+ministres%22&hl=en)". I don't know if this might indicate that the use of this construction was influenced by French grammar.

I also found examples from Google Books of *our* being used "like an adjective" in other contexts: for example, after the determiner *any* (e.g. "[any our Subjects](https://books.google.com/books?id=48pTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22any+our%22&hl=en)" or "any our dominions").

---

To be clear, I'm not only interested in "other our dominions", but also in other phrases of the same structure, like "other his books", "other my shoes" or so on. I want to know the grammar of this construction, when it was used, and when it stopped being used.

Comment: "other our" could be a transcription error made when copying a draft or taking dictation.  What did scribes do to correct such errors?  I wonder if there are earlier drafts of these documents that include "other our" or "other of our", which was in use at the same time (apparently, e.g., in the Magna Carta).

Comment: I seem to recall that this collocation of a quantifier or demonstrative determiner with a possessive determiner (*any my servants*, *these our commands*, *this his friend* &c) was not uncommon in EME, and lingered particularly in legal contexts into the 18th century.

Comment: I'm convinced, from Google Ngram's results (there are of course false positives). Still playing devil's advocate, the peculiarity may be in the use of "other" (or "any") rather than "our."

Comment: It seems to me as though it has been replaced with 'other dominions of ours'. 'other books of his' etc.  But it is an interesting treatise of an EME construction you have given us. Thanks.

Comment: @StoneyB: I wasn't sure whether to count examples like "these our commands" and "this his friend" the same way because they seem like they might be possible to a certain extent in modern English too (although I'm not sure if a comma would be required: "these, our commands" or "this, his friend")

Comment: @sumelic [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=29NeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA172&dq=%22this+his+friend%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidjKC-uY7dAhVph-AKHS9TASc4MhDoAQg4MAM#v=onepage&q=%22this%20his%20friend%22&f=false)'s an instance where I think that parsing is impossible. . . . And it's not like the [Det][Det] construction is entirely obsolete: we still say "**all her** dominions".

Comment: @StoneyB: Right; "all" can be used directly before a(nother?) determiner, which is clear from examples like "all the dogs". As I say in this question, though, it seems to me that  "our" is not in fact being used as a determiner in "other our dominions", although I don't know if I can prove that

Comment: I wonder if this construction could be essentially what some languages have as a "partitive genitive". I know modern German uses partitive genitive, so possibly earlier English did too? But as genitive became less obviously distinguishable, it might make sense that people preferred to clarify by switching to the "of" prepositional phrase, until saying it with "of" became essentially the only way to mean a partitive.

Comment: @bof Those are appositive, and I don't think the original example can be.

Comment: Compare *other our* and *other of our* in nGrams. There's a contradiction to the assumption of "stop being used." Both prevailed and declined similarly, with *other of our* much more frequent.

Comment: @Kris: I'm not sure what you mean. How does the fact that "other of our" has been used for a while contradict my statement that "other our" (in contexts like "other our dominions") is not used in modern English? I think the usage that I am interested in is too old for the Google Ngram Viewer to be a particularly useful tool for analyzing it. It doesn't seem to have good data for either "other our" or "other of our" before 1650.

Comment: @Kris: And as you get closer to the present, an increasing percentage of the hits for "other our" occur in contexts like "each other our" (e.g. in sentences like "We tell each other our choices and intentions")

Comment: @sumelic I have cross checked with the actual related to the timeline. Current usage of *other our* in most cases is not in the sense we are dealing with, as you have noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find much, but did find an explanation in a scholarly edition (published originally at the end of the 19th century) of William Caxton's [Blanchardine and Eglatine](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/Blanchardyn/1:5.1.2.2?rgn=div4;view=fulltext) from ca. 1498. There must be more modern info sources available, but I didn't happen upon them..

According to the editor, in the 14th and 15 centuries there was a movement away from the Old English [partitive genitive](http://faculty.virginia.edu/OldEnglish/OEA/genitive.html) (In Old English for instance 'mannig mana' meant many men. The 'a' on mana was a genitive marker.) towards simple apposition of which the following examples are listed:

> Chaucer (Einenkel, p. 93): '**A busshel venym**,' IV. 267; '**no
>   morsel bred**,' III. 215; '**the beste galoun wyn**,' III. 249.
>
> E. E. Wills (ed. Furnivall): '**a peyre schetys**,' 4/16, 5/8, 41/24,
>   76/16, 101/18; '**a peyre bede**s,' 5/3.
>
> Bury Wills (Camden Society): '**a pece medowe**,' 47; '**a peyre
>   spectaclys**,' 15; '**a quart wyn**e,' 16; '**a galon wine**,' 30.

By Caxton's time however, there was a break in this development too, while an older of-genitive construction became considerably more versatile.

Nonetheless traces remained of this appositive use. Examples from *Blanchardyn* include "other" used to mean "other of" and "any" meaning "any of".

> **Other is used for 'others of.'**  'Other her gentyll women,' 76/31; 'other his prysoners,' 121/25.
>
> Also any occurs for 'any of':—'Affermyng that I oughte rather
>   tenprynte his actes and noble feates than of Godefroy of boloyne or
>   ony the eight.'—Caxton's Preface to Morte Darthur, 2/1.

So that may go some way to answering your question: 'other his prisoners' seems to correspond to 'other our dominions'. Although to be honest, there seems a bit of explaining missing between the genitives of quantity (a galon wine etc.) to genitives of the form 'other his prysoners'.

Comment: After thinking (much later) about it, I've accepted this answer, as I've since found out that even "other the" and "any the" could formerly be found in expressions like "other the like" and "any the like".  So the change does seem to have been in the usage of words like "other" and "any", rather than in the usage of words like "our" (as I first thought).